# Dihedral Group Inner Automorphism

Tags: group-theory, proof-writing

I have to prove $D_n\cong\textrm{Inn}(D_n)$, for $n\geqslant 3$. I know that $R_{180}$ is not in any odd dihedral group and so the centers of the groups are all trivial. I'm just not sure where to take the proof from there.

Comment: As stated this is not true, for example the group of inner automorphisms of $D_8$ is isomorphic to the Klein-4 group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let define the following group homomorphism:
$$\iota:\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
D_n & \to & \textrm{Aut}(D_n)\\
x & \mapsto & y\in D_n\mapsto xyx^{-1}
\end{array}\right.$$
Then, one has: $$\ker(\iota)=Z(D_n)\textrm{ and }\textrm{im}(\iota)=\textrm{Inn}(D_n).$$
From there, one has: $$\textrm{inn}(D_n)\cong D_n/Z(D_n).$$
For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ odd, as you said $Z(D_n)=\{\textrm{id}\}$, then: $$\textrm{Inn}(D_n)\cong D_n/\{\textrm{id}\}\cong D_n.$$

**N.B.** For $n$ even, one has: $$\textrm{Inn}(D_n)\cong D_n/\{\textrm{id},-\textrm{id}\}.$$